# IBM Guardium - full sql is empty

Tags: database, informix

I have one question with Appliance IBM Guardium. I create Security Policy with Category (Audit, Access, Activity) and Rules include Log full details. Then I create Dashboard to show information about (Client Ip, DB Protocol, DB User name, Server IP, timestamp, SQL and Full SQL). It shows all rows, but Full SQL is empty.
The question is - where must I configure in the appliance to show the Full SQL parameter in Dashboard Report or it is something else?

[image]

- Database: Informix 11.7.
- Guardium: 11.4v
- CentOS: 7v

Comment: Zero experience with Guardiam but a quick search on the IBM Q&A brought this: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/data-sql-field-ibm-security-guardium-reports-not-same-being-executed-andor-different-data-full-sql-field
Maybe enabling those two settings will help.

Answer (score 0):

You must create your report based on Full SQL entity.
If you created your report based on SQL entity, it won't display Full SQL values.

Hope it helps.

[FULL SQL Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms2Qw.png)

Comment: I selected both variants but Full SQL don't return results.

Comment: got it. There's a report called "Full SQL by DB Username", try it out, just make sure that username = % and Select a range from 1 week and let's see your result.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/1LrRvKL        I selected this attribute, but don't return nothing full sql rows.

Comment: This looks like a comment, not an answer. Asking a question is something that should be done in a comment, so that the user gives you the information before you post your answer.  If your guess is wrong, then your answer may be irrelevant or incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for images, both attributes are correct, just make sure that you creaded your report based on Query domain= Access and Main Entity= FULL SQL

Comment: I just modified my answer and attached an image for references

Answer (score 0):

Full sql is collected depending on your policy rules and actions.
To have full sql data you need a rule with action log full details to fire
Be careful when defining such rules as full sql might fill up you Guardium collector, make sure you log only data that you need.
There are a few user communities and forums for Guardium users where you can get useful answers, I don’t think stack overflow is the right place.
Linked In is one place to look